# FATAL EXCEPTION: ThumbnailManager-1 while sharing images to Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-sharing, android-fileprovider

I got following Exception while sharing images using FileProvider. Following is the code I used to.

```
{

  ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
  files.add(getImageUriFromCache(context,bitmap,fileName));

}


private void startSharingIntent(ArrayList<Uri> files,String caption){
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            i.setType("image/png");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my app share");
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,caption);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,caption);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Tital"));
        }

public Uri getImageUriFromCache(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage , String fileId) throws IOException{

                File cachePath = new File(inContext.getFilesDir() , "images/");
                cachePath.mkdirs(); // don't forget to make the directory
                File newFile = new File(cachePath, "im"+fileId+"_post.png");
                newFile.setReadable(true, false);
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(newFile); // overwrites this image every time
                inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.close();
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(inContext, "com.xx.xx.fileprovider", newFile);
                return contentUri;
}
```

Detail stack trace of exception is as follows.

```
08-11 09:02:47.943: I/Choreographer(428): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-11 09:02:48.343: D/dalvikvm(1832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 287K, 8% free 4686K/5048K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
08-11 09:02:48.353: I/dalvikvm-heap(1832): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.200MB for 583180-byte allocation
08-11 09:02:48.403: D/dalvikvm(1832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 8% free 5223K/5620K, paused 35ms, total 40ms
08-11 09:02:48.693: E/CursorWindow(1832): Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0 columns.
08-11 09:02:48.713: W/dalvikvm(1832): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ac1b90)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): FATAL EXCEPTION: ThumbnailManager-1
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Process: com.android.mms, PID: 1832
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:574)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:102)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.getOrientation(UriImage.java:546)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.mms.util.ThumbnailManager$ThumbnailTask.requestDecode(ThumbnailManager.java:490)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.mms.util.ThumbnailManager$ThumbnailTask.onDecodeOriginal(ThumbnailManager.java:439)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.mms.util.ThumbnailManager$ThumbnailTask.getBitmap(ThumbnailManager.java:342)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.mms.util.ThumbnailManager$ThumbnailTask.run(ThumbnailManager.java:252)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 09:02:48.773: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-11 09:02:48.793: W/ActivityManager(377):   Force finishing activity com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity
```

Images are shared correctly when I choose email to share, but failed when I select messaging. Please assist.

Comment: Any update on this, AMY?  Seeing a very similar issue on samsung devices when sharing to their Messaging app (which is a fork of Android's com.android.mms app, I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the sources, the Android [`UriImage`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/ab845dee6565a8dfc384186bc8f2e801a2b087e1/src/com/android/mms/ui/UriImage.java#546) class (of the Mms app) tries to read the orientation of the image you provide. It does that by running a `query` on the `Uri` you provided asking for the `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION` column.

I didn't find recent sources of the FileProvider class, but this older [FileProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java#421) version only supports two column names:

- `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`
- `OpenableColumns.SIZE`

If none of these two columns are requested it will just return an empty row (with no columns at all).

In your case the empty row causes the MMS app to crash when it requests a column with the index `0`.

So what can you do?

I see at least three possible options. All of them involve creating your own Subclass of `FileProvider` which overrides the `query` method.

It depends on your goal and skill levels which one is best for you. I try to list them from "simple" to "quite a bit of work".

- check the `projection` array and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if any column other than `DISPLAY_NAME` or `SIZE` appears in it. This should work because the MMS app seems to ignore this exception. This might break other apps though.
- check the projection and append the requested `ORIENTATION` column with a value of `0` (indicating the image doesn't need any rotating).

  Here is some (untested) code to implement this:

  ```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
    {
        Cursor cursor = super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        if (    cursor == null &&
                projection != null
                && projection.length == 1
                && MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION.equals(projection[0])) {
            // query from MMS app, return a single row with a 0 value
            final MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(projection, 1);
            matrixCursor.addRow(new Integer[]{0});
            cursor = matrixCursor;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
  ```
- check the projection and append the requested `ORIENTATION` column with the actual value from the EXIF tag, if present in the image.

Comment: I tried finding a way to add the orientation tag (with ContentValues) to the Uri to set the orientation parameter, but was unsuccessful (default FileProvider doesn't implement the `insert` method). How would you implement the second bullet point (override `query` in a custom FileProvider)?

Comment: I tested it out and it worked (with minor changes). Thanks!